# AngularJS vs ServerSide rendering

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, model-view-controller, mean-stack

A colleague of mine at work proposed a challenge the other day. The problem:  Solve one of our common problems human resource management ie. assigning ppl to projects. The one caveat was we had to do so using a technology that neither of us had used. So we set out building this project using the MEAN stack. Its been a fun learning experience thus far, but it has me wondering.

At what point do we decide that server side MVC rendering trumps client side MVC rendering. Most of the customers we work with already have an instance of IIS running somewhere, so we would using use asp.net MVC, which obviously will do most of the HTML rendering on the server side. Even when using angular in combination with node the HTML rendering is server side.

But if we couple angular with IIS we can do full client side HTML rendering. At what point have others made the decision to use Client vs Server HTML Rendering? Are there concerns of slowness on mobile platforms?

What does the community say are the pros and cons of each scenario?

Thanks for the thoughts!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've gone with a pure separation between the client and server.  My server stack relies on PHP (using PDO and ph-pass) and MySQL for persistence.  The major advantage in my view is the complete decoupling of the view/presentation from the server side logic.  It is absolutely clear in my application that the PHP generates data and returns it formatted as JSON and accepts JSON formatted parameters but has nothing to do with the display (it just creates data structures that are easily parsed on the front-end).

On the front end I'm using AngularJS, UI Bootstrap (angular wrapper for bootstrap), Google Maps V3 Javascript api (wrapped in an angular directive), and D3js (again wrapped in an angular directive).

The few sites I've worked on haven't really encountered any issues on mobile... even when doing some pretty heavy data processing on the front end... I do all my filtering and some aggregation in the client side code for displaying filterable markers on a map and to draw some charts.  Unfortunately the app I'm currently referring to is about a week from being made live so I can't show a link ATM.

Here's my main site though, this one isn't dependent on any PHP so all Angular:
http://www.intellectual-tech.com

You can also check out the portfolio sites and http://www.shanklandfinancial.com I did all of these with just AngularJS and no server side code.  The site that does rely on a database but is still WIP is http://www.eat-data.org

The longest delay is still in fetching the initial data which is in the 60kb range after gzipping.  On mobile the google maps drags things down quite a bit and CSS animation isn't smooth/fast, but everything is still useable.

Another plus is if at some point I decide AngularJS isn't the way to go, or the client wants a native app, the server side code is all entirely re-useable without modification.

The only down side I see really is if the client wants to export the views I don't really have a good means to do that... I've recently used the PHPExcel library to output the data as XLSX files but in terms of charts etc. nothing in my server code is so fancy and would require overhaul if this was required.  That said I don't think this is real problem that having printer friendly pages to be "printed to PDF" can't solve.

Comment: I personally love [AngularJS](http://www.angularjs.org/), but feel the answer above was very opinionated. I have been struggling with the fact that server-side rendering is much faster and always will be unless the client is a super-computer or the browser's use of modern GPU functionality for newer computers can suddenly outperform the server's ability to merge presentation views with data (HTML templates and content).

Comment: Honestly, most 'small' or even moderate websites really don't care this much about performance, so more power to them - use what you want! If you're asking this question, then you probably care with or without a business case driving it. The most recent, biggest, and well-documented case study I can think of related to this choice is [Twitter switching back from client-side to server-side](http://openmymind.net/2012/5/30/Client-Side-vs-Server-Side-Rendering/).

Comment: *Forgot to mention: servers also benefit from being able to cache the merged result, where-as client templates always have to perform the merge.

Comment: Hi Eric, these are all good points.  In all honesty I felt held back to answer in the way I did for some of the reasons you mention.  The reason I decided to post this answer is because I've been very focused on mobile development recently and had some cases where I decided to try letting the front end do a bit more work to avoid the round trips (since on mobile these can be very costly time wise).  It turned out for my cases (small or medium size jobs) everything performs pretty well even on mobile platforms.  That said if I was doing a enterprise scale project I wouldn't give this advice.

Comment: Great point! If the user's network IO is slower than the client rendering performance (like mobile in some cases), then it doesn't matter how fast your server is.

Comment: I just visited http://www.shanklandfinancial.com and turned off javascript. I was greated with a blank page. This is how google see's your web page when it tries to visit it with the bot. I can see some source code, but the actual content is nowhere to be seen. This is major issue.

Comment: @SynackSA I'll be honest I'm not sure that I turned on Prerender.io for that site in particular, if not I should do it.  Using Prerender.io it sends a cached version of the page after the JS has been loaded using PhantomJS to present the compiled page to search engines for SEO purposes.  Can see an example here if you include _escaped_fragment_ in the query params it shows the page as sent back from prerender.io view-source:https://www.intellectual-tech.com/welcome?_escaped_fragment_ if you leave out the query param you'll see the JS without the processing.

Comment: Also if you Google Shankland Financial Google was able to parse the page well enough to get it up on the top of the page (at least for my results), though for better control over how that processing turns out Prerender.io is a nice solution (they offer the code if you want to run it yourself).

Comment: Is using PhantomJS faster than justing using a node server to render the code?

Comment: Sort of... not in the regular case but since prerender.io caches the result of parsing the page and sends that out and if you use their service the load isn't going to your servers it's "lighter" in this case.  Phantom is bigger than node but angular 1.x wasn't written to be processed server side.  I believe there's some headway on making that work with 2.x but not entirely sure on that.